# What should I add to this code to make it a full working js autoclicker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have just started writing a afk checker bypass for a website running with js but I need help with the code because Im very new in the js.
What I want to do:
I want to write a script that click when a windows opens or modal I dont know what is it there is two buttons and a timer -I'll write down the code- one of the buttons "Evet" makes me show online and hides the message box and the other button "Hayır" makes me log off so I want to write a script that autocliks the Evet button the timer is 30secs and If you dont click "Evet" in 30 seconds it automaticly clicks "Hayır" and logs off.

here is the box.

```html
<

    <div id="musercontrol" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog bounceInDown animated">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header font-weight-bold text-uppercase d-flex py-3 align-items-center bg-danger text-white">
                    <div class="mr-1"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-id-badge fa-w-12 fa-fw fa-2x py-0" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="id-badge" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512" data-fa-i2svg=""></svg><!-- <i class="far fa-id-badge fa-fw fa-2x py-0"></i> -->&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="flex-fill">Orada mısınız ?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body d-block text-justify">
                    <div class="mb-2">you are afk now</div>
                    <div class="mb-2 text-center font-weight-bold">stay online?</div>
                    <div class="small font-italic text-muted mb-0">counter started.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer d-flex py-1 align-self-stretch">
                    <a href="/safe-logoff/" class="btn btn-danger d-flex align-self-stretch text-uppercase">
                        <div class="align-self-center mr-2"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-times-circle fa-w-16 fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="times-circle" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""></svg><!-- <i class="far fa-times-circle fa-fw"></i> --> &nbsp;Hayır</div>
                        <div class="align-self-center small">(<span id="musercontroltimer" data-seconds-left="30" class="jst-timeout"></span>)</div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="flex-fill"></div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success text-uppercase" onclick="hidePortalTimeOut()"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-check-circle fa-w-16 fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="check-circle" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""></svg><!-- <i class="far fa-check-circle fa-fw"></i> --> &nbsp;Evet</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var PortalTimeOutStatus=0;
        var PortalTimeOut=360000;
        $(function(){setTimeout(function(){showPortalTimeOut();},PortalTimeOut)});
        function showPortalTimeOut()
        {
            PortalTimeOutStatus=1;
            $('#musercontroltimer').html('');
            $('#musercontrol').modal({backdrop: "static"});
            $('#musercontroltimer').startTimer({onComplete:function(){ if (PortalTimeOutStatus==1){location.href='/otomatik-safe-logoff/'}}});
        }
        function hidePortalTimeOut()
        {
            PortalTimeOutStatus=0
            $('#musercontroltimer').html('');
            $('#musercontroltimer').trigger('complete')
            $('#musercontrol').modal('hide');
            setTimeout(function(){showPortalTimeOut();},PortalTimeOut)
        }
    </script>
```

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         auto click for x
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      3.0
// @description  auto click afk check button
// @match        bad website
// @author       ace
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
window.onload=function ace(){

  setInterval(ace,5);
}
function ace() {
document.querySelector(document).ready(function() {
  document.querySelector("a:contains('Evet')").click();
});
};
```

I tried this and take error from chrome that is:
Error code: "SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED"

Edit1: I Changed and removed something for copyrighhts.

Edit 2:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         auto click for x
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      3.0
// @description  auto click afk check button
// @match        bad site
// @author       ace
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
window.onload=function ace(){

  setInterval(ace,5);
}
function ace() {
 document.querySelector(document).ready(function() {
    var doc = document.querySelector(document).querySelector("a");
    doc.each(function() {
       if (document.querySelector(this).text() == "Evet") {
         document.querySelector(this).click();
       }
    });
  });
};
```

I tried this one but this gave me nothing on website.
Edit 2 end.

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message and your attempts to resolve the error

Comment: I dont know anything else these all I have and one more script I tried but that one gave me nothing. I will add as edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this one but also get the exceeded error

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         auto click for x
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      3.0
// @description  auto click afk check button
// @match        bad website
// @author       ace
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
window.onload=function ace(){

  setInterval(ace,5);
}
function ace() {
document.querySelector(document).ready(function() {
  document.querySelector("button:contains('Evet')").click();
});
};
```

Comment: please make an edit to your question instead of an answer